# Deploying Gatsby App to Azure with secrets

Tags: azure-devops, gatsby

In the [instructions](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/deploying-to-azure/) to deploy a Gatsby app to it relies on a Github repository to deploy. But my repository specifically ignores (ala .gitiignore) files that contain secret keys. What is the best way to deploy a Gatsby app to Azure with secrets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be using [Secure files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?view=azure-devops) in azure devops.

Go to Azure **project** portal --> **Pipelines**-->**Library**-->**Secure files** Tab-->click **+ Secure file** to upload the files which contain secret keys to azure devops server.

[image]

Then you can consume the secure files in a Pipeline by using [Download Secure File task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-secure-file?view=azure-devops).

After the secure file is downloaded in the pipeline, its path can be referenced in the pipeline as `$(mySecureFile.secureFilePath)` (`mySecureFile` is the name given to the task). Alternatively, downloaded secure files can be found in the directory given by `$(Agent.TempDirectory)`

You can also use [Copy files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to move the secure file around in the agent machine.